# Can we characterize the set of functions satisfying $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx= \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

> Can we characterize the set of functions that satisfy the following?
>
> $$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx= \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \quad\text{and}\quad f(0)=0$$

This came up at the back of my head while wondering about fundamental theorem of calculus applied to the Gaussian integral(which I know won't work but nvm). Does this yield some interesting solutions?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is an obvious solution. Other than that we can always say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ needs to be $0$ since otherweise the integral would be unbounded. So the set of solutions are those functions with $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x) dx =0, f(0)=0, \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=0$. There should be quite alot of those.

Comment: To make the last point obvious: $f(x)=-x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\frac 1{2x^2}$ for $x>1$. The integral is $0$. The boundaries are also satisfied.
If you require continuity or differentiability we could always regularize $f$ with a $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$  function by some convolution (shouldn't change our integral).